# Misbehaving custom checkbox in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to customize checkbox in my android app. For that i have created 2 images check_on and check_off. But my checkbox is going to left corner instead of center of text before space. Why it is behaving like that? Below is my code.

Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:onClick="vmPlayer"
            style="@style/contentRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/voicemailCheckbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">               
            </CheckBox>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/voicemailname"
                style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/voicemailCheckbox"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="james-panterranetworks-com"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextViewStyle.medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/voicemailname"
                android:layout_below="@+id/voicemailname"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/length"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Dec 19, 2012 / 14:25:07" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/length"
                style="@style/TextViewStyle.medium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/voicemailname"
                android:layout_below="@+id/voicemailname"
                android:text="00:32"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

checkbox drawable

```
<style name="myCustomCheckbox" parent="android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_checkbox</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: can you post a picture of how you want the checkbox will be located and what is the current result of your code? because I don't understand what is "is going left corner instead of center of text before space" means

Comment: this line may be the cause of your problem 
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/voicemailCheckbox"
you set the first textView to be located right of the checkbox

Comment: oh now I see what you want to do.. first you need to set the checkbox location on the screen.. in the design view you can drag it and it's will add the code to the xml file..

Comment: check this: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/multi-selection-listview-android-with.html